# Syntax highlighting Markdown on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting, markdown

I am writing a basic Markdown editor and wish for the Markdown to be syntax highlighted. There seem to be plenty of resources on how to have code *within* Markdown highlighted, but I want the Markdown *itself* to be syntax highlighted. Are there any existing JavaScript/jQuery libraries for doing so? If not, where is a good place to start crafting my own?

Answer (score 2):

[highlight.js](http://highlightjs.org/) seems to support markdown syntax.

Comment: @Shai, I don't agre that it's a "link-only" answer. tsvallender is searching for a syntax highlighting library that supports markdown, and highlight.js is one that may meet tsvallender's need. Linking that name to its official site just makes it easier to find that library.